# problem in integrating the slave code in attiny 84

Tags: arduino-uno

I tried the whole process by using two arduino unos.It worked perfectly.
Though when i tried to replace the slave uno with attiny 84 uC it showed following errors in compiling.

```
Arduino: 1.6.7 (Windows 7), Board: "ATtiny24/44/84, ATtiny84 @ 1 MHz  (internal oscillator; BOD disabled)"

WARNING: Category '' in library ArduinoJson is not valid. Setting to 'Uncategorized'
C:\Users\LEGEND\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_8a75bcb6a2713182a57eb1014198ceb3\sketch_may12c.ino: In function 'void setup()':

sketch_may12c:12: error: 'SPCR' was not declared in this scope

   SPCR |= bit (SPE);

   ^

In file included from C:\Users\LEGEND\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\tiny\hardware\avr\1.0.0\cores\tiny/WProgram.h:12:0,

                 from C:\Users\LEGEND\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\tiny\hardware\avr\1.0.0\cores\tiny/Arduino.h:4,

                 from sketch\sketch_may12c.ino.cpp:1:

sketch_may12c:12: error: 'SPE' was not declared in this scope

   SPCR |= bit (SPE);

                ^

C:\Users\LEGEND\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\tiny\hardware\avr\1.0.0\cores\tiny/wiring.h:158:25: note: in definition of macro 'bit'

 #define bit(b) (1UL << (b))

                         ^

sketch_may12c:15: error: 'MISO' was not declared in this scope

   pinMode (MISO, OUTPUT);

            ^

sketch_may12c:22: error: expected unqualified-id before '.' token

   tinySPI.attachInterrupt();

          ^

C:\Users\LEGEND\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_8a75bcb6a2713182a57eb1014198ceb3\sketch_may12c.ino: In function 'void SPI_STC_vect()':

sketch_may12c:30: error: 'SPDR' was not declared in this scope

 byte c = SPDR;  // grab byte from SPI Data Register

          ^

exit status 1
'SPCR' was not declared in this scope

  This report would have more information with
  "Show verbose output during compilation"
  enabled in File > Preferences.
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the core.

Comment: It has to do with SPI.

Comment: Could you post the content of `sketch_may2c.ino` as it seems this is where the erroneous code is.

Comment: #include <SPI.h>

char buf [100];
volatile byte pos;
volatile bool process_it;

void setup (void)
{
  Serial.begin (115200);   // debugging

  // turn on SPI in slave mode
  SPCR |= bit (SPE);

  // have to send on master in, *slave out*
  pinMode (MISO, OUTPUT);

  // get ready for an interrupt
  pos = 0;   // buffer empty
  process_it = false;

Comment: continued.....................

  // now turn on interrupts
  SPI.attachInterrupt();

}  // end of setup


// SPI interrupt routine
ISR (SPI_STC_vect)
{
byte c = SPDR;  // grab byte from SPI Data Register

  // add to buffer if room
  if (pos < sizeof buf)
    {
    buf [pos++] = c;

    // example: newline means time to process buffer
    if (c == '\n')
      process_it = true;

    }  // end of room available
}  // end of interrupt routine SPI_STC_vect

Comment: continued..................
// main loop - wait for flag set in interrupt routine
void loop (void)
{
  if (process_it)
    {
    buf [pos] = 0;
    Serial.println (buf);
    pos = 0;
    process_it = false;
    }  // end of flag set

}  // end of loop

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compile the wrong program for the wrong chip.

The nice thing about the Arduino core library is that it enables you to
write code that is portable across various Arduino boards. However, this
library provides very limited access to the capabilities of the
underlying hardware. Then, it is quite common for users to mix Arduino
code with C statements that directly access the hardware registers.
Doing this provides full control over the hardware, at the cost of
reduced portability.

Just an example from your code:

```c++
SPCR |= bit (SPE);
```

This line is accessing the control register of the SPI port (SPCR means
“SPI Control Register”) in order to set to 1 the bit named SPE (for “SPI
Enable”). This is the “bare metal” way of turning on the SPI port.

Now, your problem is that, unlike the ATmega328P powering your Unos, the
ATtiny84 does *not* have a hardware SPI port. Thus the line above just
makes no sense.

The solution: you have to figure out some other means for your chip to
talk SPI. You could emulate it purely in software, but it would
certainly be more efficient to use the USI port. The USI (“Universal
Serial Interface”) is a multipurpose serial port found in many ATtinies.
It can be configured to do SPI, I2C or simplex/half-duplex UART.

Recommended readings:

- [AVR319: Using the USI module for SPI
  communication](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc2582.pdf), an
  application note by ATmel
- [Using an ATtiny2313/4313 as SPI
  master](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/USI-SPI) on the Arduino
  Playground

You may be able to find ready-made libraries for doing this.